# Help with finding the difference (delta) from a value returned from the last two records

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm using MS SQL 2005 and I have created a CTE query to return values from the last two records. I then use this to find the delta of two figures returned. I have a working query of sorts but 
I'm having problems getting anything other than the delta figure.

here is my query:

```
;with data as(
    SELECT 
        NetObjectID,
        RawStatus,
        RowID,
        rn 
    from(   
        SELECT 
            CustomPollerAssignmentID AS NetObjectID,
            RawStatus,
            RowID,
            row_number() over(order by DateTime desc)as rn 
        FROM CustomPollerStatistics_Detail 
        WHERE
            (CustomPollerAssignmentID='a87f531d-4842-4bb3-9d68-7fd118004356')
    ) x where rn<=2
)
SELECT 
    case when 
        max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) > max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) 
    then 
        max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) - max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) 
    else 
        max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) - max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) 
    end as Delta
from data having 
(SELECT 
    case when 
        max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) > max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) 
    then 
        max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) - max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) 
    else 
        max(case rn when 2 then RawStatus end) - max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) 
    end
from data) >= 1
```

What I'm after is to get the Delta & NetObjectID returned. Each time I try, I get errors.
`data.NetObjectID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause.`

If I try adding group by etc.. to the end of the query I get further error complaining about the word 'group'.

I'm relatively new to SQL and I am picking things up as I go. Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if something like this will work.

```
;with data as
(    
    SELECT         
        NetObjectID,        
        RawStatus,        
        RowID,        
        rn     
    from
    (               
        SELECT                 
            CustomPollerAssignmentID AS NetObjectID,                
            RawStatus,                
            RowID,                
            row_number() over(order by DateTime desc)as rn         
        FROM CustomPollerStatistics_Detail         
        WHERE                
        (
            CustomPollerAssignmentID='a87f531d-4842-4bb3-9d68-7fd118004356'
        )    
    ) x 
    where rn<=2
)
select
    NetObjectID,
    max(RawStatus)-min(RawStatus) as Delta
from data
group by NetObjectID
```

Comment: I did not think to use max() and min() in that way. Nice....

Yes, this returns what I need, though I would like to include the "having x > y" clause. Any Ideas??

Comment: what do you want the having clause to do?

Comment: I dont know if you know, or heard, about an application called Solarwinds - Network Performance Monitor. With this application I can design alerts based on a certain trigger. This SQL is one such trigger. Basically, when the Delta is greater than 48, I want a result but when its less than 48, I want nothing. Almost a true / false type response.

Comment: All sorted.. Just my naivety with SQL. I was trying to place the "having x > y" clause BEFORE the "group by ..." when it should be AFTER.

Comment: ok.  why have another application do that when you can design your own trigger on the table or set up a job that checks the value at a regular time span?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm very new here and I'm unsure of CTE queries, however it looks like after you define Data, you are selecting case ... as Delta FROM....  Meaning you only have Delta in your select statement.  Again, sorry if I'm way off base.

Comment: Thanks for your response, 
In the select if I have 
SELECT 
 NetObjectID, 
 case .... 
From data ....

I get the error as above but what I dont quite understand is that if I have this: 
SELECT 
 max(case rn when 1 then RawStatus end) as Current, 
 case .... 
From data 
.... 

I get the figure for Current as well as Delta.